# Usage of has_many relationship to save records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and kind of confused by the has_one and has_many relationship.

I have two models - USER and LOCATION.

Each USER has a location and a LOCATION can belong to many USERS.

So, I created it this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Now when I want to create a new user and save the location, how should I do it?
Is this the way ???

```
@user = User.new
@user.name = params[:name]

@loc = Location.new
@loc.zip = params[:zip]
@loc.save

@user.location = @loc
@user.save
```

This is not right and is not working for me. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

The rails books specify only how to create these associations. Not as to how to save the records with these associations.

Comment: It should be work when you change '@user.loc = loc' to '@user.location = loc'

Comment: You need to say how it is failing. What is the error message? Also, what are the columns on the tables? Did you create `location_id` on the `users` table?

Comment: do you have location_id as a field on User?

Comment: Thanks Andrew France and rovermicrover. I had assumed Rails to create the foreign key based on the association specified. Once I added it, the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

change `save` for `save!` to raise an exception and see what is not working for you.

An alternative way would be

```
@loc = Location.create!(:zip => params[:zip])
@user.create!(:name => params[:name], :location_id => @loc.id)
```

you might enjoy receiving something like `params[:users][:name]` as parameter, because for instance if there are more attributes than name you can just do

```
@user.create(params[:user])
```